# Why is a dist folder being created in all the directories in my local repository

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, graphql

I am working on a project which is using Apollo graphql server, Unit testing frameworks like Mocha, Chai, Sinon and nyc.

I really don't understand why does my project creates a `dist` folder in all the directory in the project after every few minutes on save. I have never seen this behaviour in any of my other local repositories.

I can't find this on any forums. Is it because of the Apollo graphql server I am using?

my script looks like this

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "npx standard",
    "test:unit": "mocha test/**",
    "coverage": "nyc --reporter=text --reporter=cobertura mocha test/**",
    "lint:fix": "npx standard --fix",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "crypto": "node test.js"
  },
```

Comment: How do you run your environment? Check `package.json` for the script that runs your development mode. There will be a watcher that watches file changes and builds when one occurs.

Comment: updated the question with the scripts i use @gurisko

Comment: What IDE are you using? Do you have any other config files in your main directory? (`nodemon.json`, ...)

Comment: I am using vscode. The other files are just dockerfile, bitbucket yamls, .nycrc, and docker-compose.yml. I don't think they have anything to do with this.